# python script stop when cannot connect to second ip?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I write a python script for read some ip in 10 line.
The lines are called with the for loop and connect with ssh.
When the script cannot connect to the third IP, the script stops

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import paramiko
import sys
import os
with open('list2', 'r') as ip:
  ip = ip.readlines()
  for i in ip:
    i = i.rstrip("\n").split(":")[1]
    print('=========================BEGIN=========================')
    print(i)
    host = i
    user = 'root'
    password = '123456'
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    conn =  ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
    a = stdout.read().strip()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo hello")
    b = stdout.read().strip()
    print ( str(a) + "" + str(b) + '\n' )
print('==========================END===========================')
```

How can the script continue even when an ip is not available?

Comment: what is the Traceback ?

Comment: Add exception handling to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import paramiko
import sys
import os
with open('best.txt', 'r') as ip:
    for i in ip:
        try:
            i=i.strip('\n').split(":")
            host = i[0]
            port = i[1]
            print('=========================BEGIN=========================')
            print(host)
            user = 'root'
            password = '123456'
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            conn =  ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password, port=port)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname")
            a = stdout.read().strip()
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo hello")
            b = stdout.read().strip()
            print ( str(a) + "" + str(b) + '\n' )
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError:
            pass
print('==========================END===========================')
```